# Toggle color of SVG icons

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want the fill color of this SVG icon to change once I click on it and change back when I click on it again. How do I do this?
I preferably want to do this using Javascript.

```css
.remove svg{
  fill: gray;
  opacity: 0.8;
  height: 50px;
  width: 45px;
}
.remove svg:hover{
  fill: red;
  opacity: 0.7;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
}
 button{
  appearance: none;
  width: 47.5px;
  height: 50px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: relative;
  background: white;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
    <button class="remove">
     <svg version="1.1" id="Capa_1" id="removeB" class="removeB" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
  viewBox="0 0 328.51 328.51" style="enable-background:new 0 0 328.51 328.51;" xml:space="preserve">
  <polygon points="229.044,88.858 164.255,153.647 99.466,88.858 88.858,99.466 153.647,164.255 88.858,229.044 99.466,239.651 
   164.255,174.862 229.044,239.651 239.651,229.044 174.862,164.255 239.651,99.466"/>
      </svg>
    </button>
```

Comment: start by searching (1) how to handle click with JS (2) how to change CSS with JS, etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I modified your CSS codes by only adding "clicked" class and I also wrote a simple JS script. Here is how you can do this by JS:

```
.remove svg{
  fill: gray;
  opacity: 0.8;
  height: 50px;
  width: 45px;
}
.remove.clicked svg{
  fill: red;
  opacity: 0.7;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
}
 button{
  appearance: none;
  width: 47.5px;
  height: 50px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: relative;
  background: white;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```
    var button = document.querySelector("button");

    button.addEventListener("click", function(){
        this.classList.toggle("clicked");
    });
```